# NA at the end of column using na.locf function

Tags: r, zoo

I am substituting NA with the last occuring value in the column using the `zoo` package and `na.locf`. My problem is that the function fails if there s not numbers in the last row. Please see my example.

```
> tail(Dax1Dax2Dax3)
          Time    Res1    Accum1    Res2    Accum2    Res3    Accum3
2   2017-10-18 -109.41 171103.61    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
1   2017-10-20 1174.60 172278.21    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
406 2017-10-23    <NA>      <NA> 1473.25 185076.53    <NA>      <NA>
664 2017-10-25    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>  -80.19 188974.10
663 2017-10-26    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>  398.16 189372.27
662 2017-11-07    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA> -348.37 189023.90

require(zoo)

Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1 <- na.locf(Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1, fromLast = TRUE)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Accum1, value = c(253L, 253L, 253L,  : 
  replacement has 913 rows, data has 917

> dim(Dax1Dax2Dax3)
[1] 917   7
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what you want to happen with those cases where the last value is `NA`

Comment: I guess repeat the last value in that column

Comment: In that case first do `na.locf(..., fromLast = TRUE)` and then without `fromLast = TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these depending on what you want.  The first two leave the trailing NAs in place and the third alternative extends the last value.

```
# 1
Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1 <- na.locf(Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)

# 2
Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1 <- na.locf0(Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1, fromLast = TRUE)

# 3
Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1 <- na.locf(Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1, fromLast = TRUE, rule = 1)
```

See `?na.locf` for more information.

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
          Time    Res1    Accum1    Res2    Accum2    Res3    Accum3
2   2017-10-18 -109.41 171103.61    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
1   2017-10-20 1174.60 172278.21    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
406 2017-10-23    <NA>      <NA> 1473.25 185076.53    <NA>      <NA>
664 2017-10-25    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>  -80.19 188974.10
663 2017-10-26    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA>  398.16 189372.27
662 2017-11-07    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>      <NA> -348.37 189023.90"

Dax1Dax2Dax3 <- read.table(text = Lines, na.strings = "<NA>")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `fill` function from the `tidyr` package to impute `NA` with the last value.

```
library(tidyr)
Dax1Dax2Dax3 %>% fill(Res1, Accum1, Res2, Accum2)
#           Time    Res1   Accum1    Res2   Accum2    Res3   Accum3
# 2   2017-10-18 -109.41 171103.6      NA       NA      NA       NA
# 1   2017-10-20 1174.60 172278.2      NA       NA      NA       NA
# 406 2017-10-23 1174.60 172278.2 1473.25 185076.5      NA       NA
# 664 2017-10-25 1174.60 172278.2 1473.25 185076.5  -80.19 188974.1
# 663 2017-10-26 1174.60 172278.2 1473.25 185076.5  398.16 189372.3
# 662 2017-11-07 1174.60 172278.2 1473.25 185076.5 -348.37 189023.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using the na.locf function of the **imputeTS** package might be an option. It has a handy  **na.remaining** parameter, which lets you choose, what to do with the remaining NAs. Which helps a lot in cases like this.

```
library("imputeTS")
Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1 <- na.locf(Dax1Dax2Dax3$Accum1, na.remaining = "rev")
```

These are the options of the na.remaining parameter:

- "keep" - return the series with NAs
- "rm" - remove remaining NAs
- "mean" - replace remaining NAs by overall mean
- "rev" - perform nocb / locf from the reverse direction